# the partial derivatives computing

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that:
$u_{xx}^{''}=u_{yy}^{''} \;,  \;
u(x,2x)=x \;,  \;
u_{x}^{'}(x,2x)=x^{2}\;,  \;
$
How to find the following values?
$u_{xx}^{''}(x,2x)=?\; 
u_{xy}^{''}(x,2x)=? \;  
u_{yy}^{''}(x,2x)=?\; $

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we have $u(x, 2x) = x$, the chain rule gives 
$$ u_x(x,2x) + 2u_y(x,2x) = 1 $$ 
As $u_x(x,2x) = x^2$, we have $u_y(x, 2x) = \frac{1-x^2}{2}$. Starting with $u_x(x,2x) = x^2$, the chain rule gives 
$$ u_{xx}(x,2x) + 2u_{xy}(x,2x) = 2x \tag 1 $$
and starting with $u_y(x, 2x) = \frac{1-x^2}{2}$, we get
$$ u_{xy}(x,2x) + 2u_{yy}(x,2x) = -x \tag 2$$
Subtracting (2) twice from the equation (1), we get
$$ u_{xx}(x,2x) - 4u_{yy}(x,2x) = 4x $$
As $u_{xx} = u_{yy}$, we have 
$$ u_{xx}(x,2x) = u_{yy}(x,2x) = -\frac 43x $$
And hence, by (2)
$$ u_{xy}(x,2x) = -x + \frac 83 x = \frac 53 x. $$